# Is it possible to use the MySQL LIKE directive in an ElementCriteriaModel?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

In a plugin, I'd like to pull all Assets with filenames starting with a certain string (the `$prefix` variable, in the below examples).

It's possible to do this with a custom DbCommand:

```
$results = craft()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('assetfiles.*')
    ->from('assetfiles assetfiles')
    ->where(array(
        'like',
        'assetfiles.filename',
        $prefix.'%',
    ))
    ->queryAll();
$assets = AssetFileModel::populateModels($results);
```

However, I'd like to do this using an ElementCriteriaModel. The below doesn't work:

```
$assets = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset, array(
    'filename' => 'LIKE "'.$prefix.'%"',
    'limit' => null,
))->find();
```

In the above example, is the syntax off, or is not possible to use LIKE in an ElementCriteriaModel parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` wildcard character should do the trick.

c.f. https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax

```
$assets = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset, array(
    'filename' => $prefix.'*',
    'limit' => null,
))->find();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Michael! (I edited in a working example)

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to use the `search` parameter like this:

```
$assets = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset, array(
    'search' => 'filename::'.$prefix.'*',
    'limit' => null,
))->find();
```